# Java - No se me copia en el segundo fichero los mismos datos que en mi primer archivo

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente, creo un primer archivo con el nombre de dni y creo aleatoriamente en su interior 20 números dni aleatorios, una vez creado se crea un segundo fichero en el que se deberían adjuntar los 20 números junto con el calculo de la letra.

El problema es que en el primer fichero se me crean unos números aleatorios al azar y en el segundo fichero se me copian otros diferentes y se les adjunta la letra del dni.

También un problema es que en el segundo archivo donde se copian se repite el mismo numero y no de forma aleatoria.

Alguna idea al respecto?

**Adjunto codigo** (*pido disculpas ya que es muy extenso y no sabia como resumirlo*):

```
public class Main {

    static Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        //pregunto la ruta donde quiero guardar los archivos y llamo metodos
    }

    //aqui va un metodo para crear el primer archivo si no existe lo crea

    public static void insertarFicheroUno(String directorio,String fichero) {


        BufferedWriter fichero;

        try {
            fichero = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(//ruta));

            int[] texto = new int[20];
              for (int i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
                //asignamos variable y le colocamos el metodo del dni para que realice el bucle
                 texto[i] = //nombre variable;
              }

            for (int lineas : texto) {
                fichero.write(lineas + "\n");
            }
            fichero.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("La operacion no se ha realizado con exito");
        }
    }

    public static int obtenerDNI() {
    //metodo obtetener dni

    }

    public static String calcularNIF(int nif) {

        //metodo que calcula la letra del dni
    }


    public static void combinarFichero(String directorio,String fitxeroUno) throws IOException {

        //insertamos metodo de insertar fichero


        String RutaOriginal = //ruta del fichero;
        String RutaNueva = //ruta del fichero nueva;

        //llamamos a buffered write y buffered reader y a cada file le asignamos un nombre

        if(!fl.exists()) {
            System.out.println("No existe el archivo!");
            return;
        }

        f3.createNewFile();

        try {
            //asigna la clase buffered con el nombre de las rutas que necesitamos


            //copiamos metodo copiar

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(buffWrite != null) {
                buffWrite.close();
            }
            if(buffRead != null) {
                buffRead.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void copiar(BufferedWriter escribir, BufferedReader leer) throws IOException{ //metodo para copiar los datos de un archivo a otro
        String linea=leer.readLine();
        int nif = obtenerDNI();

        while(linea!=null){
            escribir.write(calcularNIF(nif)+"\n");          
            linea=leer.readLine();
        }
    }
//aqui va un metodo para ver el contenido de los archivos
}
```

**Esto es lo que se me muestra por pantalla:**

```
DNI: 
62009512
34580057
81208643
51899405
27560786
80268231
85309980
99910872
33788661
64580176
89533004
49222392
30944010
34753590
33530627
69044392
64179106
85506122
35988162
37955902

NIF: 
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
54829634-A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Java - No se me copia en el segundo fichero los mismos datos que en mi primer archivo

El problema radica en este método:

```java
public static void copiar(BufferedWriter escribir, BufferedReader leer) throws IOException
{ 
    String linea=leer.readLine();
    int nif = obtindreDNI();

    while(linea!=null)
    {
        escribir.write(calcularNIF(nif)+"\n");          
        linea=leer.readLine();
    }
}
```

Si nos damos cuenta, la variable `linea` en ningún momento la usas y la cuestión es que esa variable es la que nos da acceso al contenido del primer archivo (donde están los `DNI`). Entonces si usas la variable `nif` y la pasas al método `calcularNIF`, estarías calculando la misma letra en cada iteración, debido a que, la variable nunca cambia y esa es la razón del porque el segundo archivo **siempre** tendrá el mismo `DNI` y letra.

**La solución** es usar la referencia del objeto al que apunta la variable `linea` y posteriormente habría que convertir la cadena en un dato de tipo `int` (con el método estático [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))), debido a que, el parámetro del método `calcularNIF` es de ese tipo.

El código quedaría así:

```java
public static void copiar(BufferedWriter escribir, BufferedReader leer) throws IOException
{ 
    String linea=leer.readLine();
    while(linea!=null)
    {
        escribir.write(calcularNIF(Integer.parseInt(linea)) + "\n");          
        linea=leer.readLine();
    }
}
```

De este modo debería de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Es verdad la quite para usar el metodo en el otro fichero y no la volvi a colocar pero me mareo el codigo no encontraba el fallo, muchisimas gracias!!!!!!